# QUnit and Sinon, testing XHR requests

Tags: microsoft-metro, qunit, sinon

I'm relatively new to unit testing and i'm trying to figure out a way to test an XHR request in a meaningful way.

1) The request pulls in various scripts and other resources onto the page, I want to make sure the correct number of resources are being loaded, and that the request is successful.

2) Should I use an actual request to the service that is providing the resource?  I looked at fakeserver and fakexhr request on sinonjs.org, but I don't really get how those can provide a meaningful test.

3) I'm testing existing code, which I realize is pretty pointless, but it's what i'm required to do.  That being said, there is alot of code in certain methods which could potentially be broken down into various tests.  Should I break the existing code down and create tests for my interpreted expectation?  Or just write tests for what is actually there?.... if that makes any sense.

Thanks,
-John

Answer (score 3):

I find it useful to use the sinon fakeServer to return various test responses that will exercise my client-side functions. You can set up a series of tests in which a fakeServer response returns data that you can use to subsequently check the behaviour of your code. For example, suppose you expect ten resource objects to be returned, you can create pre-canned xml or json to represent those resources and then check that your code has handled them properly. In another test, what does your code do when you only receive nine objects?

Begin writing your tests to cover your existing code. When those tests pass, begin breaking up your code into easier-to-understand and meaningful units. If the tests still pass, then great, you've just refactored your code and not inadvertently broken anything. Also, now you've got smaller chunks of code that can more readily be tested and understood. From this point on you'll never look back :-)